# Phundament and Vagrant, VCS assets

Tags: php, yii2, phundament

So I know for installation, generally you need to run `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.0-beta4"` before you create the project with composer. However I was following the instructions for working directly in vagrant, which went swimmingly until I loaded up the backend and tried to generate the docs. running `./yii app/setup-docs` throws:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>
> No driver found to handle Asset VCS repository http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/2.1.2/jquery.sparkline.min.js

I'm not exactly sure if the composer asset plugin was supposed to be incorporated in the vagrant file somehow, or if it needed to be run manually?

Comment: Did you run composer inside the container eg. with `vagrant docker-run web -- composer install` or on your host machine?

Comment: yes, but it couldn't handle the VCS repo. It needed the plugin, and somehow I had managed to miss installing it? I ended up running it in the VM itself. Worked as a temporary solution.

Comment: You don't have to see this as a temporary solution, in fact the `phundament/app:development` container ist meant to do that development task.
You *can* run composer outside the container, if you make sure everything is set up correctly - the main reason for this is, that the composer update and install commands are faster than in the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give an answer which might also help other people using **Yii 2.0, Vagrant or Docker**, I need to point out a few things.

The error occurs, because of the missing asset plugin on your host machine, there are several open issues (as of Jan'15) about this behavior, see [#3607](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3607) and [#3082](https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/3082).

But it is a feature of *Phundament* to provide a *fully-set up development environment*, with all plugins and packages pre-installed (but also updatable) and working. Therefore, when you run commands or scripts within a container or VM, they'll work (fingers-crossed).

As pointed out in a comment above, running `composer` in a VM or container is *usually slower* than on your host machine.

So as a summary: If you have your development (host-)machine set up correctly you may run `composer` there. If you're unsure use the container.

*Full disclosure: I am the author of Phundament.*

Answer (score 0):

And right after I posted this, I looked back at my console history and realized I didn't `sudo`. running `sudo composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.0-beta4"` installs the plugin.

D'oh.

Comment: Worked as a temporary solution, that is.